# How to observe a Firestore document with AngularFire? `onSnapshot() not working?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Using Angular 14 and AngularFire 7.4.1, I made an observer for a Firestore collection. It works great:

```js
interface Scientist {
  name?: string | null,
  born?: number | null,
  accomplishment?: string | null
};

scientist$: Observable<Scientist[]>;

constructor(public firestore: Firestore) {
    this.scientist$ = collectionData(collection(firestore, 'scientists'));
}
```

The collection displays in the HTML view.

I see in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) that it's also possible to observe a single document. I'm a big fan of Charles Babbage so I want to observe this document:

```js
interface Scientist {
  name?: string | null,
  born?: number | null,
  accomplishment?: string | null
};

scientist$: Observable<Scientist[]>;
charle$: Observable<Scientist>;

constructor(public firestore: Firestore) {
  this.scientist$ = collectionData(collection(firestore, 'scientists')); // works
  this.charle$ = onSnapshot(doc(firestore, 'scientists', 'Charles Babbage')); // doesn't work
}
```

That throws an error:

```
Type 'Unsubscribe' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Scientist>'.
```

Oh yeah, Firestore returns my data wrapped in a document. Let's change the data type to `any`:

```js
charle$: Observable<any>;
```

That throws the same error. There seems to be something incompatible between Angular's `Observable` and Firestore's `onSnapshot`. Is there a AngularFire single document observer, e.g., `documentData(doc(firestore, 'scientists', 'Charles Babbage')`?

I have a second, related question. How do I detach the collection listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onSnapshot()` returns a function that can been called to detach the listener. It also takes a function as second param that'll trigger every time an update is received. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(firestore, 'scientists', 'Charles Babbage'), (snapshot) => {
  console.log("> Updated received", doc.data())
  // TODO: Update data state
});
```

You can then update the state from the function itself. Just call the `unsub();` and the listener will be detached.

Comment: Thanks, I'll write another answer with the complete, working code. I'll also post a new question about detaching the collection listener.

Comment: And what Typescript type is `snapshot`? I made it `any`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code based on Dharmaraj's answer.

```js
import { Firestore, doc, collectionData, collection, onSnapshot } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

interface Scientist {
  name?: string | null,
  born?: number | null,
  accomplishment?: string | null
};

export class AppComponent {
  scientist$: Observable<Scientist[]>;
  charle$: Scientist  = {
    name: null,
    born: null,
    accomplishment: null
  };
  unsubCharle$: any;

  constructor(public firestore: Firestore) {
    this.scientist$ = collectionData(collection(firestore, 'scientists')); // collection listener
    this.unsubCharle$ = onSnapshot(doc(firestore, 'scientists', 'Charles Babbage'), (snapshot: any) => { // document listener
        this.charle$.name = snapshot.data().name;
        this.charle$.born = snapshot.data().born;
        this.charle$.accomplishment = snapshot.data().accomplishment;
    });
  }

  async detachListener() {
    console.log("Detaching listener.");
    this.unsubCharle$();
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Observe (collection)</h3>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let scientist of scientist$ | async">
        {{scientist.name}}, born {{scientist.born}}: {{scientist.accomplishment}}
    </li>
</ul>

<h3>Observe (single document, 'Charles Babbage')</h3>

<div *ngIf="charle$.name">{{ charle$.name }}, born {{ charle$.born }}: {{ charle$.accomplishment}}</div>

<form (ngSubmit)="detachListener()">
    <button type="submit" value="detachListener">Detach Listener</button>
</form>
```

This makes two observers, a collection listener and a document listener. The document listener can be detached.